# Artificially modify server load in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, load

I am curious if it is possible artificially modify the server load in Ubuntu or more generally linux. I am working on an application that reacts to the server load, and in order to test it it would be nice if I could change the server load easily.

I am currently running an over-active program that will literally generate load, but I'd prefer to not continue overheating my laptop (it's getting hot!).

Comment: How is your program reading the server load? What language are you using? Using an "overactive" program will be able to make your CPU usage go up, but you can't virtually make it lower that way.

Comment: I am reading it from /proc/loadavg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `chroot` to run the various pieces of software you're testing with a specified directory as the root directory. Set up a manufactured/modified /proc/loadavg relative to that new root directory, too.

`chroot` will let you create a dummy file that **appears** to have /proc/loadavg as its path, so the software will observe your manufactured values even if you can't change your code to look for load data in a different location.

Comment: This may not artificially modify the server load, but the idea is so damn clever I can't help but reward it.

Answer (score 6):

One of the most important things to know about Linux (or Unix) systems is, everything is just a file. Since you are just reading from `/proc/loadavg`, the easiest was for you to accomplish what you are after is simply make a text file that contains a line of text that you would see when running `cat /proc/loadavg`. Then have your program read from that file you created instead of `/proc/loadavg` and it will be none the wiser. If you want to test under different "artificial" situations, just change the text in this file and save. When your testing is done, simply change your program back to reading from `/proc/loadavg` and you can be sure it will work as expected.

Note, you can make this text file anywhere you want...in your home directory, in the program directory, wherever. However, you shouldn't make it in `/proc`. That directory is reserved for system objects.

Comment: I can appreciate that I can just change my code. I was curious if there was a tool or method for doing this within linux. Since it's an open source operating system, presumably it should be possible to change the results of /proc/loadavg

Comment: Not really @GoldenNewby ... the contents of the `/proc` directory are created by the Linux Kernel itself. It's actually an entire filesystem (procfs) that's designed to provide a sort of interface between kernel level information (system load, RAM data, running processes, etc.) and user level programs (ie, your terminal). So you can't really "write" to files within `/proc/` like you can in other places. And even if you could (you can with root permissions), it would be deleterious to your system, because a lot of system processes use the information in this directory.

Comment: Yeah, I get that a lot of processes use the value of /proc/loadavg to display information. I also understand that the /proc directory isn't a standard area of the filesystem (and they aren't even files really).  I was more looking for an explanation on how I might be able to interface with the kernel to change these values, or if there were tools already that let you do that. I assume at this point there are not, but I'll wait a bit just in case.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `stress` command, see http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/

> A tool to impose load on and stress test a computer system

```
sudo apt-get install stress
```

To avoid CPU warm, you can install a virtual machine with small cpu capacity. virtualbox and qemu-kvm are free.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to **actually/literally** stress the machine, something like [stress](http://weather.ou.edu/~apw/projects/stress/) is not what you are after.

As stated, /proc/loadavg would be the place to [set system load averages](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/get-cpu-system-load-average-on-ubuntu-linux/) (faux loads).

But if that's also not the meat of what you're after, I would absolutely suggest

[getloadavg](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getloadavg)

[watchdog](http://linux.die.net/man/8/watchdog)

and even possible [Munin plugins](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins)

Comment: Well that's how you get the load average, not how you set it. The other suggestions aren't useful, because I am using this to test monitoring software.

Answer (score 0):

There're two methods.

**Hacking /proc/loadavg**

- The machine is not overstressed
- Your program reads load valus from a file

*Todo:* hack Linux to report fake load value

**Modify your prg**

- The machine is not overstressed
- Your program reads load valus from a file

*Todo:* change 4 characters in your prg: replace */proc/loadavg* with */tmp/loadavg*

You can decide now. Calculate costs ;)

Comment: "I understand that it would be easier to simply make my program read a fake version of /proc/loadavg, but I'm interested in a solution that actually changes what linux reports."

Comment: There's no difference between reading a textfile and reading a textfile. Also, if you fake the load some way, it will produce fake values/trends/changes, so it will be unusable for testing real-life scenario. The problem is not how to make Linux to report fake values but produce values looks real.

Comment: Not really. I'm attempting to compare how my software deals with an increase in server load compared to other already packaged binary tools out there. Ones which I don't have access to to change where they read the load average from.

Comment: The hack may be done with `mount --bind /tmp/loadavg /proc/loadavg`.